# bash sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Getting `` sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command ``
in bash script

Here is snippet:

```
que=`cat temp | grep -o -P '(?<=uid").*(?=text)' | sed -e 's/\\/ /g' | sed -e 's/["]//g' | cut -d ":" -f3 | cut -d "," -f1`
```

I searched some other answers on here but none of helped.

Comment: Why call `sed` twice?

Comment: please show us sample input and expected sample output in code tags so that we could help you here.

Comment: You need not to use these many commands for tasks, 1 single `sed` or `awk` or `grep` could work, please post samples in post.

Comment: @e0k to remove backslash and double comma

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 however i used sed to remove backslash and double comma from text. so input is > How "\are\" you?- And output should be > How are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
sed -e 's/\\/ /g'
```

Because it's inside backticks, the `\\` is being replaced with `\`. You need to double-escape it:

```
sed -e 's/\\\\/ /g'
```

Answer (score 3):

Switch from backticks to `$(your command)`.

Comment: This `$()` syntax can also be nested